# ios diagnosing iphone connection status

Tags: ios, crash, connection

I am trying to make my iPhone app more robust, by ensuring that it doesn't crash when there is no network connection. Right now the app attempts to make a connection on startup immediately, through the app delegate. It has no issues if wifi or cellular is available, but it will crash if there is no network connection visible. I have looked around on this site and haven't found anything that quite fits my problem. I have the feeling it should be just a simple line of code, like an objective-c equivalent of a pseudo- 'isConnection', or something similar:

```
if (isConnection) {
    - sendSynchronousRequest for json data I'm using
    - manipulate the data, etc., and continue with normal operations
} else {
    - send an output message to a view controller, 
      letting the user know what's wrong.
}
```

I can't seem to isolate the (admittedly abstract) "isConnection" condition that I'm looking for, specifically. Does anyone have experience or advice with this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reachability class is very easy to use.  Download the class files here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

*You also need to add the SystemConfiguration.framework*

Here's the code you need:

```
-(BOOL)isConnection {
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    //replace www.google.com with your own host you're checking for
    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (hostStatus != NotReachable) {
        //There are also other status enums like
        //ReachableViaWiFi
        //ReachableViaWWAN (3G/LTE)
        //if you need to detect if user is on cellular, act accordingly
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Then you can call your method:

```
if ([self isConnection]) {
    //do something
} else {
    //no connection, inform user
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you unaccepted my answer? The fellow you accepted posted a link to the project but no sample code.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't even realize what I've done - your answer also contributed to my understanding of this issue. I don't even know what unaccepting means... ok, is that the green check mark? I'll check that now, and let me know how I can undo whatever it is I've done! I did not mean to dis you at all! Sorry! I'm just a newb where this site is concerned.

Comment: Ah, I see - you can only check one checkmark. So... does the checkmark represent the comment that led most directly to my understanding? If so, it seems a bit of a weird system, since most of the time, learning seems to come from a combination of several inputs. Anyway - I've left the check beside your comment, sorry about that. But does that mean that now the other guy has had his check removed, and will now be PO'd at me for removing his?

Comment: The checkmark indicates the submission that you chose as the correct "answer" to your question and you can only choose one. On StackOverflow answering questions earns reputation points. I noticed my points went down and went to see why, and saw that you "unaccepted" my answer. The little arrows above and below the number near the checkmark are for "votes", which also earn reputation points. You can vote answers up or down depending on how helpful they are. I voted your question "Up" which awards you points

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I get it now. I'll try to remember that, as I'm finding this site to be one of the most helpful sites that exist, and I expect I'll be using it for quite a while. For ios coding I find it's near the top of the list in almost any google search. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Reachability class that Apple provides in the [Reachability sample application](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). Not only does it tell you if you're connected, but how you're connected (WiFi, cellular or no connection at all). You can even register for a notification when the connection status changes.

Even though you can use that to check the connection status before initiating the code you describe above, I still think you should investigate why the app crashes when you have no connection, and attempt to resolve it. You could always lose connectivity in the middle of a request attempt, and you don't want that to crash the app either.